# Find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ when $y+x=x^{-y}$.

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have to determine the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.
The answer of the solution and my answer are different. I don't know where I made a mistake. Could you please help me find it.

**My solution:**

$y+x=x^{-y}$

$\ln(y+x) =(-y)\ln(x)$

$\frac1{y+x}\big[\frac{dy}{dx}+1\big] =-\frac{dy}{dx}\ln(x)-\frac yx$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\big(\frac1{y+x}+\ln(x)\big)=-\frac1{y+x}-\frac yx$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\big(\frac{1+y\ln(x)+x\ln(x)}{y+x}\big)=\frac{-x-y-xy}{x(x+y)}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x-y-xy}{x(x+y)}\cdot\frac{x+y}{1+\ln(x)(x+y)}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-(x+xy+y)}{x+x(x+y)\ln(x)}$

**Given solution:**

$y+x=x^{-y}$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$,

$\frac{dy}{dx}+1=x^{-y}\big[-y\frac{dy}{dx}\ln(x)+\ln(x)\frac{d}{dx}(-y)\big]$

$\frac{dy}{dx}+1= x^{-y}\big[\frac{-y}{x}-\ln(x)\frac{dy}{dx}\big]$

$(1+x^{-y}\ln(x))\frac{dy}{dx}=-1-y\cdot x^{-y-1}$

$\implies\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1+y\cdot x^{-y-1}}{1+x^{-y}\ln(x)}$

Comment: Write the solutions here using latex, so that it is readable.

Comment: It shouldn't be a requirement for a new user to immediately be proficient in MathJax. Work was shown, and the question is a fair question.

Comment: yes,I am new here and don't know how use those tools.sorry guys for your anxiety.Thanks @quasi for understanding me.

Comment: @Andronicus Rather than posting such a short and coarse comment, you could welcome the OP to MSE and kindly explain that we use MatJaX here to format our maths. Then point him to the [MathJaX tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) on Meta. Otherwise you run the risk that new users turn away from MSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that $y+x=x^{-y}$, the answers are equivalent, and yours is a simpler answer, and a better method. Good work!

To see the equivalence, take the book's answer and replace $x^{-y}$ by $y+x$, and $x^{-y-1}$ by ${\large{\frac{y+x}{x}}}$, then simplify.

Comment: Thanks a lot @quasi .Is there any common way to check the equivalency of two different solutions.I have many problems like that in which I have implemented my method rather than book's one and the answers are seeming not the same.can you tell me any procedure of checking the equivalency please.

Comment: As a quick spot-check, plug in a few test values. Another way is to graph the two results (using a graphing utility).

Comment: are those test values have to be random @quasi ?

Comment: As an immediate spot-check, I would choose input values for which the output values are obvious.

Comment: I tried to plot the graph of this two solutions using desmos. But i think here is a problem.that is there are two variables in one solution .so desmos is not plotting any graph.what to do now @quasi ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75909/discussion-between-rakibul-islam-prince-and-quasi).

Comment: could you please tell me the procedure of checking the equivalency of two integrals @quasi ?